# Trouble with the XPATH for Facebook posts

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

So basically I was making a Facebook we scrapper for a school project using selenium and I had it scroll ten times to ensure that all the posts loaded and then go back up and screenshot/like all ten post and I had it working for about a week.

```
# Scroll to the bottom of the page to load more posts
scroll_height = 0
num_scrolls = 10
for _ in range(num_scrolls):
    scroll_height += 1000
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {scroll_height});")
    time.sleep(2)

post_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]")

# Scroll the page to load more posts
for i, post_element in enumerate(post_elements):
    if i >= 10:
        break
        
    # Scroll to the post element to ensure it's in view
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", post_element)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -100);")  # Adjust scroll position to avoid overlapping with Facebook header
    time.sleep(2)  # Add a short delay after scrolling to allow the post to load

    # Take a screenshot of the post
    

    # Like the post
    try:
        like_button = post_element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[text()='Like']")
        like_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        print(f"Could not like post {i+1}")
        
 #   screenshot_name = os.path.join(folder_name, f'post_{i+1}.png')
 #   driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_name)

# Quit the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

I think Facebook updated their website because now it just loads the ten posts and then it crashes so I tired updating the XPATH from "//div[@role='article']" to "//div[@role='main']" which kind of worked because it loaded the ten post and scrolled all the way back up and went to the first post and liked it but then it quits and doesn't like/screenshot the rest of the post. I just need help figuring out the correct XPATH (I even tried the full XPATH but it still doesn't work) or if it's something else I'm not seeing.

Comment: First Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them so I would suggest telling your school that they probably should pick something else to do as school assignment. And yes you are correct. Facebook updates their website all the time. So just because it worked a few days ago doesn't mean it will work now.